# Delete from all joined tables MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have to delete rows from many tables which I have joined together. I know that you can write something like:

`delete tableA, tableB, ..., tableZ from tableA join tableB on...`

What I'm wondering is if there's something like `*` for deletion, such that

`delete * from tableA join tableB on...`

Would delete all matching rows from all tables joined, or if there is no such shortcut for this and you must write the name of each table for deletion after delete.

Comment: There is nothing like * with delete command. Writing the whole query without * and no where cond. would delete all the rows matching the join condition.

Comment: Thank you. I'm assuming a where condition would limit the delete to the table(s) where the condition column exists?

Comment: No, it deletes from all tables joined, unless you're left/right joining and there's no corresponding row in a table. But the `where` does not limit deletion to a table mentioned in `where` clause.

Comment: I am left joining, which requires the identifiers or an identifier error will occur. Good to know for general joins though